# Is it possible to sort Elasticsearch aggregations groups result by nearby? (JAVA)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, grouping, aggregation, bucket

I am trying to use Elasticsearch aggregations to group merchants with the same title and sortby my current location.

I had done something like this, but it only sort the subdocuments

```
POST _search{  
   "aggs":{  
  "group_by_merchantTitle":{  
     "terms":{  
        "field":"title"
     },
     "aggs":{  
        "group_by_top_hits":{  
           "top_hits":{  
              "size":20,
              "sort":[  
                 {  
                    "_geo_distance":{  
                       "loc":[  
                          {  
                             "lat":3.00,
                             "lon":100.0
                          }
                       ],
                       "unit":"m"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

}
    }

what i want is the group it self is sort by nearest to me.

Comment: can you share your schema mappings/settings and few sample document.

Comment: hmm, grouping the documents then sort by nearest to me, which seems your loc which is datapoint of type geo. Do you consider that this is not a concrete data point for the aggregation to work. A group can have documents with different geo points, how are you handling then, if you want nearest one, i doubt ES don't have any functionality to achieve this.